Deleted project may be blocking DNS name usage in new projects
I am using the following command to create a DNS Managed Zone (using mydomain.net as example here):
$ gcloud dns managed-zones create my-dns-zone \
    --description="Managed zone" \
    --dns-name="mydomain.net." \
    --visibility="public"

and gettings this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zones.create) HTTPError 400: The domain 'mydomain.net.' (or its child domains) may be reserved or registered already, prohibited by policy, or there may be no DNS name server shards remaining for the name. For more information see https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#nameserver_limits.

The project I am using has no managed zones:
$ gcloud dns managed-zones list
Listed 0 items.

I shut down a project yesterday that had a DNS Managed Zone for the same domain. I did not destroy the resource explicitly before shutting it down. So I suspect that the deleted project has active resources that prohibit me from using the same domain in the new project. However, after shutting it down, the old project does not seem to be accessible anymore using gcloud or in the console.
Is it likely that the old project is the issue here? What options do I have for resolving this? What else might be causing the issue?
